# How to update git version on RHEL?

Tags: redhat

I just created a fresh RHEL VM on GCP to play some Kubernetes on it.

It was not having any git installed on it.

I used `yum` package manager to install git on it, but it didn't installed the latest version of git.

**Current Version:** 2.38.0 / 3 October 2022

**Version Installed by yum:** 1.8.3.1

Answer (score 5):

Create a file:

```
touch gitupgrade.sh
```

And add the following to it:

```
yum -y remove git
yum -y clean packages
mkdir tempgit
cd tempgit
yum install -y autoconf cpio curl-devel expat-devel gcc gettext-devel make openssl-devel perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker zlib-devel
wget -O v2.24.1.tar.gz https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.24.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ./v2.24.1.tar.gz
cd git-2.24.1/
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git
make && make install
ln -sf /usr/local/git/bin/* /usr/bin/
cd ..
rm -fr git-2.24.1
cd ..
rm -fr tempgit
echo "results"
which git
git --version
```

The run it to upgrade:

```
sudo sh gitupgrade.sh
```

And that’s a wrap

Comment: Adding a citation for this answer since it came from this website by Travis Media: https://travis.media/how-to-upgrade-git-on-rhel7-and-centos7/

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Oracle Linux, CentOS, Scientific Linux, et al.
RHEL and derivatives typically ship older versions of git. You can [download a tarball](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/) and build from source, or use a 3rd-party repository such as the [IUS Community Project](https://ius.io/) to obtain a more recent version of git.

Comment: I am new to linux environment, I tried to do that but RHEL doest even have wget, make.

Ever after installing both it still through some error that some libraries are missing.

Comment: [check this](https://linuxconcept.com/install-git-on-rhel-7-operating-system/) I'm not use RHEL  before my distro is ARCH

Answer (score 0):

The base Git version on RHEL 8 is quite old:

```
sudo dnf -y install git
# Package git-2.31.1-3.el8_7.x86_64 is already installed.
```

But you can upgrade Git with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). If you don't have Homebrew yet, first install it:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

# Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

**To install Git with Homebrew:**

```
brew install git

# Reload bash_profile to see the new version of Git:
. ~/.bash_profile # or . ~/.bashrc 

git --version
# git version 2.40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy 3 steps, works absolutely fine.

## 1. Install a package with repository for your system:

## On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:

$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

## On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:

$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

## 2. Install the collection:

$ sudo yum install rh-git29

## 3. Start using the software collection:

$ scl enable rh-git29 bash

#Check version:

$ git version

git version 2.9.3

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-git29/